# Android BLE disconnect every 40 seconds and reconnects again after 20 seconds

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I am implementing an Android app the connects to BLE device. Every time the device is connected to the mobile, it automatically disconnects after 40 seconds and then auto-reconnect after 20 seconds. This issue is very significant on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 running Android 4.4.2.

Why this auto-disconnect happens? and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @PaulFreez not yet !! but till now power cycling BT prevents this problem. May be there is another better solution.